# parsing a JSON field in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using RDBMS with JasperReports.  One field in a table stores data in JSON format.  How can I create a report that show a data parsed from the JSON fields?

I'm thinking about creating an external jar with a static method that receives a JSON path and return the corresponding data.  I'm not sure that this is a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a scriptlet to perform the parsing. Then you can use the scriptlet result in the report, like any other field/parameter/variable. Take a look [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/)